# Do I have to pass in the exact same program account to the program if I want to do CPI with the program account?

Tags: anchor, cpi

I'm developing a on-chain Solana program with Anchor. Let's call this Program A. Inside an instruction of Program A, it'll perform a CPI to invoke Program B. I want to pass Program A as an account during the CPI.

My question is: should I have to also include Program A itself as an account when sending the transaction from the client side? This is somewhat funny, because I have to define a `#[Accounts]` struct for Program A like this:

```
#[Accounts]
pub struct FooInstruction<'info> {
    /// CHECK: We only need the Pubkey of this account
    #[account(address = crate::ID)]
    pub this_program: UncheckedAccount<'info>,

    pub program_b: Program<'info, ProgramB>,
}
```

What the runtime is executing now is exactly `this_program`, and I should still pass in `this_program`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the transaction should be initiated with knowledge of all relevant accounts. In other words, all accounts that will be utilized should be identified during the creation of the transaction. This is necessary as the CPI requires program account info, which is not retrievable at runtime. Therefore, it's essential to provide this information during the making transaction.